# How to know the sentence/phrase should using gerund or continuous?

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds, present-continuous

I'm currently learning about gerund and I tried to create a sentences such as

"When your parents are getting old"
or
"When your parents getting old"

which one of those is correct? is the second example is gerund?

Answer (score 1):

Continuous tenses have a form of *to be* before them.  Adverbs can be between the form of *to be* and the *-ing* word.

> I am walking to the store.
>
> You are not walking to the store.
>
> She is quickly walking to the store.

Gerunds/participles will not have *to be* before them.

> I saw her walking to the store.
>
> Walking to the store was something I hated doing.

They can have adverbs before them, but there will be no form of *to be* before them.

> I saw her begrudgingly walking to the store.
>
> Slowly walking to the store was something I hated doing.

Don't get confused if *to be* is being used in another construction like a separate verb or passive voice.

> I was thinking walking would be good for us, if we did it regularly.

*Was thinking* is the verb and *walking* is a verbal.

Comment: Begrundingly? - what does that mean when it's at home?

Comment: mispelling on my part, sorry.  "Begrudgingly" means done with resistance or protest.

Answer (score 0):

> When your parents are getting old...

This is correct: **getting** is a participle.

> When your parents getting old...

This is not correct. getting is still a participle which functions like an adjective, so it will generally have a **be** verb in front of it as in the first sentence. It is also used after verbs like **see**, which can take a participle to express a progressive action:

> I saw him cross the road - *bare infinitive: completed*
>   I saw him crossing the road - *participle: progressive*

A gerund functions as a noun. You will most likely see it as the subject or object of a verb, or link it to a sentence using a preposition. For example:

> **Getting old** brings many problems - *subject*
>   I fear **getting old** - *object*
>   I worry about **getting old** - *linked with preposition (about)*

Comment: is gerund like verb + verb and can add preposition between them?

Comment: Some people call a gerund a verbal noun. Use it like you would use a noun. "I like ice cream": ice cream is a noun. "I like walking": walking is a noun. "I want to fill my life with ice cream" note that preposition. "I want to fill my life with walking". not that preposition again.